# FULLTEXT Search (InnoDB) - Am I doing it right?

Tags: mysql

Goal: I wish to do autocomplete using ~130K global city names.

Setup: I have created a 'cities' table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS cities (
          id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          name VARCHAR(199) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY  (id),
          FULLTEXT (name)
          )$charset_collate;
```

My autocomplete code would fetch the 'name' entries and suggest them to user as user types name.

I'm using following query to fetch results:

```
SELECT name
FROM cities
WHERE MATCH (name) AGAINST (\''.$searchQuery.'*\' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

Question: Is this the right approach to take full advantage of FULLTEXT? Am I missing out on anything? Can my query be improved to fetch better results?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that. FULL TEXT is meant to be used for queries like this, so that's pretty fine to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will you want `San Jose` to come up when the user types `jo`?  If not, then `FULLTEXT` is not useful.  Instead, a simple `LIKE '$searchQuery%'` is all you need.

Because of how many rows you have (130K), consider

- `SELECT DISTINCT` -- to avoid returning dups.  (There are perhaps 328 San Jose's in the world.)
- Don't auto complete if (1) the user has typed only 1 letter, and (2) if the select returns "too many" results.
- Another thought is to `ORDER BY POPULATION DESC`.
- Add a `LIMIT` to the `SELECT`.
- Think about what to do with accents.

Comment: Thanks, Rick. No, I'd not want San Jose to show up when user types jo. I think I'm all fine with $searchQuery followed by a * to return results starting with those letters. Also, I want to know if I added the fulltext to the 'name' column correctly? Is my way of performing search the right way?

Comment: OK, `FULLTEXT` is needed.  The `MATCH...` seems right.  Most of the rest of my comments probably still apply